# How to change file paths in a Git repository, across branches, completely rewriting history?

Tags: git

I have asked a similar question before, but after doing a rather thorough analysis on the matter, came to the conclusion that `git filter-branch` is the workhorse I am looking for. Either that or a shell script that does the dirty work in `.git` itself (since git exposes its guts as part of its interface anyway).

I have a project directory which includes build scripts and build configuration definitions. More importantly, it includes `src` folder, which contains all kinds of source code for the project, and **is a git repository.**

I now realize that the entire project folder should be a git repository, not just the contained source code folder, but I wish to retain history of my source code development. In fact, I wish that the history is completely rewritten, so that instead of tracking changes in the file called say `main.c` it trackes same content changes but in file `src/main.c`. Then I can simply move files from the parent folder (where the build scripts are) and check them in the repo.

I don't want to bother with subtree merging or git submodules, or having to merge or reset anything after the repository is changed. I now have some fairly good knowledge of gits internals - commits refer to trees who refer to blobs paired with file names.

**With this knowledge, I think it should be possible to rewrite my history, prefixing all paths with `src/`**

I just don't want to do extra work, it seems that `filter-branch` is the way to go, but I get confused with examples and necessary housekeeping after its use. "Original refs"? And another problem is that I am perfectly fine with a "bare" repo, I don't need any working tree and I am not sure at all why I need the index at all either.

Answer (score 4):

It's not as simple as you think. You currently have two repositories, each with its own history.
Each commit has a well defined parent.

To get a single, chronologically correct history, you will have to change the parent of a lot of commits.

A short sample illustrates this:

Repository "configuration":

```
A <- C <- E
```

Repository "src"

```
B <- D <- F
```

Let's assume that commit B happened after A and C after B etc., so you want to have this result:

```
A <- B' <- C' <- D' <- E' <- F'
```

To achieve this you would have to change the parent of `B'` to `A`. The parent of `C'` has to be changed from `A` to `B'` etc.

That's not trivial. But possible.

Let's assume the configuration repository is located at "/usr/git/config" and the src repository is located at "/usr/git/config/src".

First, we have to prepare the "src" repository to contain all files in the "src" subfolder:

1. CD to "/usr/git/config/src"
2. Execute this monster:

   ```
   git filter-branch --index-filter 'git ls-files -s | sed "s-\t\"*-&src/-" | GIT_INDEX_FILE=$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new git update-index --index-info && mv "$GIT_INDEX_FILE.new" "$GIT_INDEX_FILE"' HEAD
   ```

The rest will now happen inside the "config" repository, so CD to "/usr/git/config".

1. Add the "src" repository as a remote: `git remote add src /usr/git/config/src`
2. Fetch the commits of the "src" repository: `git fetch src`
3. Merge the commits from "src/master" with the local "master": `git merge src/master master`
4. Find out the initial commits of the two repositories: `git rev-list --max-parents=0 --pretty HEAD`
5. Note the commit hash of the older of the two
6. Perform a rebase of the complete repository to get rid of the merge: `git rebase -f <hash from step 5>`
7. Remove the remote: `git remote remove src`
8. Remove the folders "/usr/git/config/src/src" and "/usr/git/config/src/.git"
9. Update .gitignore to no longer ignore the "src" folder.

**Please note:**
This assumes that you only have a master branch in both repositories.

Oh and: *Please* make a backup before doing this. I only tested it on a small test repository with two commits each...

---

If you only have a repository in the src subfolder, it's more simple, just execute the following:

1. CD to "/usr/git/config/src"
2. Execute the monster from above
3. Rename "/usr/git/config/src" to "/usr/git/config/src_tmp"
4. Move the complete contents of "/usr/git/config/src_tmp" to "/usr/git/config", including the ".git" repository
5. Remove the now empty "/usr/git/config/src_tmp"

Comment: @amn: It sounded like you have two repositories, one for your build configuration and one for the source. If you only have a repository for the src subfolder, it's rather simple. Please see the update.

Comment: @amn: Didn't my answer help you? If not, can you please specify what problem you are still having?

Comment: Daniel, it did somewhat but I was a bit taken aback by its complexity. After digging into gits [simple] data model, I started to write a Java  application that will edit the repository without using git. I figure, the data model is simpler than gits documentation, so I have really little to loose, apart from time spent writing the app, of which a substantial amount is written already. Anyway, thank you for the effort, sometimes one needs to know how deep the rabbit hole is before one decides on an alternative route ;-)

Comment: @amn: OK, good luck with that :) I would go with the 5 commands at the end of my answer. Looks pretty simple to me :)

Comment: I promise to get back to you with comments on my endeavour! :-) If all fails, rest assured I will execute your commands.